# set void to AsyncTask and execute it after doInBackground finishes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use `AsyncTask` to make HTTP GET requests in Android Studio. This `AsyncTask` class is used across many activities of the app. I want to assign a void function to the `AsyncTask` which will execute after the `doInBackground` has fetched the HTTP GET request. The HTTP returned response should be inserted into the `void`'s parameter. I have researched a lot of times but cannot find a simple working solution. Need Help. Thanks.

`Main.java` containing the `AsyncTask` class:

```
package com.example.NAME;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Boolean _return = false;
            
            try {
                String data = params[0];
                
                // DO THE HTTP GET REQUEST AND EVALUATE THE BOOLEAN RETURN VALUE
                _return = ???;
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return _return;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean _return) {
            super.onPostExecute(_return);
        }
    }
}
```

`Activity1.java` using the `AsyncTask` class:

```
package com.example.NAME;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {
    private final Main main = new Main();

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    }

    public synchronized void GET_Request(View v) {
        Main.GetData t = new Main.GetData();
        t.execute("STRING");
        /*
          How to attach the `after_GET_Request` void that should be executed
          after the HTTP GET Request happens and should receive the returned
          Boolean value.
        */
    }
    
    public synchronized void after_GET_Request(Boolean b) {
        // Use the Boolean data received from AsyncTask.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `AsyncTask` is deprecated

Comment: Is there any alternative method???

Comment: Threads, Background Workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a result callback to your `AsyncTask` and process the outcome:

```
public static class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ResultCallback mCallback;

    public GetData(ResultCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Boolean _return = false;

        try {
            String data = params[0];

            // DO THE HTTP GET REQUEST AND EVALUATE THE BOOLEAN RETURN VALUE
            _return = ???;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return _return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean _return) {
        super.onPostExecute(_return);
        mCallback.onResultReady(_return);
    }

    public interface ResultCallback {
        void onResultReady(Boolean result);
    }
}
```

And then in your activity call your function:

```
Main.GetData t = new Main.GetData(new ResultCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResultReady(Boolean result) {
        after_GET_Request(result);
    }
});
t.execute("STRING");
```